# integration of $\int {\frac{{dx}}{{(9 + 25x^2 )\sqrt {1 + x^2 } }} = \frac{1}{{12}}} \arctan (\frac{{4x}}{{3\sqrt {1 + x^2 } }}){\rm{ }}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, trigonometry

we have with wolfram

$\int {\frac{{dx}}{{(9 + 25x^2 )\sqrt {1 + x^2 } }} = \frac{1}{{12}}} \arctan (\frac{{4x}}{{3\sqrt {1 + x^2 } }}){\rm{ }}$

we impose the change of variable

$x^{ - 1}  = \sqrt {t^2  - 1} $

y get $ - \frac{1}{{12}}\arctan \left( {\frac{{3\sqrt {1 + x^2 } }}{{4x}}} \right)?$

Comment: I think your question is a bit unclear. Is $- \frac{1}{{12}}\arctan \left( {\frac{{3\sqrt {1 + x^2 } }}{{4x}}} \right)$ the answer you've obtained after imposing the change of variable?

Answer (score 1):

$$\int {\frac{{dx}}{{(9 + 25x^2 )\sqrt {1 + x^2 } }} = \frac{1}{{12}}} \arctan (\frac{{4x}}{{3\sqrt {1 + x^2 } }}){\rm{ }}$$ and
$$\int {\frac{{dx}}{{(9 + 25x^2 )\sqrt {1 + x^2 } }} =  - \frac{1}{{12}}\arctan \left( {\frac{{3\sqrt {1 + x^2 } }}{{4x}}} \right)} $$ is not surprising.

Note that the two results differ by a constant. This is due to the fact that if $$tan(\alpha )=
\frac{{4x}}{{3\sqrt {1 + x^2 } }}{\rm{ }}$$ and $$tan(\beta)= -  { {\frac{{3\sqrt {1 + x^2 } }}{{4x}}} } $$

Then $$ \alpha = \beta -\pi /2$$

Comment: my hint to the Weierstrass substituion gets $-1$, incredible!

Comment: Sorry, my English is bad, in the future I esserai to be more precise and concise thank you